# Change Edittext color if it is empty in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-color

How to change the edit text color if it is empty when submitting the form in 
   android.If there is any library  to handle .Answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setBackgroundColor() method of the EditText.